# Radius of convergence of a power series summing from $- \infty$ to $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

How would one go about computing the radius of convergence of, say, the following power series:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^0 n \, 3^{-n} z^n.$$

It is tempting to directly apply the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem here, but the statement is true for power series summing from $n=0$. I tried to make a substitution by realizing the sum above is equal to :

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=-m}^0 n \, 3^{-n} z^n,$$

and letting $k = n + m$ for $n= -m, -m+1, \ldots, 0$ we have

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^m (k-m) \, 3^{m-k} z^{k-m}.$$

But this seems like making things worse. Any thoughts on tackling this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-n)3^nz^{-n}$$ converges for $|z|>3$.

Comment: Can you please show me how did you transform the sum above into the sum of this form? I think it's supposed to be obvious but I have tried a lot of substitutions and none of them work. My guess would be to let $k = -n$, then my summand would be the same as yours. But then I am summing from $\infty$ to $0$.

Comment: @devianceee: $n\to-n$. Yes, this is obvious.

Comment: Okay, now I see what I have missed.